# Authorizing Google Drive service account to write pandas df to Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Co.lab notebook to write a `pandas` dataframe to a Google Sheet in my personal Google Drive account.

I have created a services account with the Google Drive API and created a API key, which is housed in Google Drive (`My Drive/project/scrapers/utils/auth_key.json`). I want to authenticate with Drive Services so I can use the Drive API to move/write Sheets into a specific folder, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606718/creating-a-spreadsheet-in-a-folder-with-gspread).

I'm having issues with authentication for the service account:

```
import os
import gspread

# Mount Google Drive

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")

# Authenticate service account

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
filepath = os.path.expanduser('/content/gdrive/My Drive/project/utils/api/service_key.json')
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(filepath, scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# Specify spreadsheet name and desired folder

title = 'test'  # Spreadsheet name.
my_path = "/project/scrapers/csv_output" # File path
destFolderId = "/content/gdrive" + "/My Drive" + my_path # Full file path

# Write spreadsheet to desired folder

from apiclient import discovery

drive_service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
file_metadata = {
    'name': title,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
    'parents': [destFolderId]
}
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
```

This results in the error `<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.".`

I *think* that this means my service account doesn't have the right permission settings, but after hours of research I'm unsure how to fix. I have given the email associated with the service account access to the Google Drive folder, and the service account has `Owner` privileges. Please help!

Comment: is accessing files from google drive also throwing errors?  once mount is complete `drive.mount('/content/gdrive')`. file can be accessed like `'/content/gdrive/My Drive/Test_Data/elephant.jpg'`.

Comment: @simpleApp I was able to mount the drive, and the filepath suggested worked! I'm now getting a different error which is `Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.` I think this may be related to the permissions of my service account, so I have updated my question and will continue to research the issue. Thank you!

Comment: i think so, the api key and scope do not match. also pls paste the complete trace log, as that will help.

Comment: @simpleApp you're right - I changed the scopes, and the query worked. The next issue I found was that I was passing a filepath when I needed a folder ID. Do you know what best practice is for this use case? Should I just delete my question?

Comment: I think it can be good for future reference. Let me filter the comments and put in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once mount is complete
`drive.mount('/content/gdrive')` file can be accessed like

```
/content/gdrive/My Drive/Test_Data/elephant.jpg
```

for

```
ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(filepath, scope)
```

verify API and its scope.